# Mule AnyPoint Studio, efficiently insert inside a DB a large number of items from array (json)

Tags: mule, sql-insert, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

i have a json like the one below as body of a POST request.

```
{
  "summary": {
    "transactionId": "5003k00000zSuNaAAK",
    "transactionNumber": "T12345",
    "overall": 100,
    "date": "15/05/2020",
    "details": [
      {
          "transactionDetailId": "CC12345",
          "product_code": 223242234,
          "price": 1500,
          "amount": 1000
        },
        {
          "transactionDetailId": "DD12345",
          "product_code": 679685675,
          "price": 1100,
          "amount": 90
      },
       {
          "transactionDetailId": "SS12345",
          "product_code": 345346643,
          "price": 2000,
          "amount": 300
      },
.......other 100 items
    ]
  }
}
```

In my AnyPoint Studio project, using a forEach module to loop `details[]` and a Bulk Insert, i'm able to execute an INSERT, and write into my postgres DB all the items of the details array. 
So, for each items an INSERT will be executed.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation, considering array with more than 1000 items?

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be to extract dteails[] as payload and then do bulk insert based on this array item. No forEach is involved and it it works much faster. Also stream is used in this case and memory demand will be much better.

Comment: If i pass the paylod containing only the array of items, i need to cycle for each item and write every items into my DB......

Comment: I would not say so. That's what bulk insert is created for. It is much better because it does this cycle inside bulk process and so it is much faster. Much, much faster.

Comment: ...how ?  how can i use Bulk Insert based on the array in my new payload?

Comment: Bulk is exactly as regular insert. Just input payload is array of items and the SQL query is like it is working with one item. You cannot use your original payload because it is not array. Extract array details and then you can use it. If you need something from original payload like transactionNumber - save it into vars and use it in the common sql from these vars. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: ...using a setPayload module  i set a new payload containing the details[] content, exactly  ```payload.summary.details``` ,  in my BULK INSERT try to call ```payload.transactionDetailId as values``` so:                                                    
                                                                                                                          ```INSERT INTO public."detailsTable"(
 "transactionDetailId", product_code, price, amount)
 VALUES (payload.transactionDetailId, ........); ```

Comment: But your payload inside Bulk insert is one item of the array. Previous payload is gone. That's why I suggested to store its values in the vars. It should look like INSERT INTO  public."detailsTable"( "transactionDetailId", product_code, price, amount) VALUES (flowVars.transactionDetailId, payload,product_code........) if you are in Mule 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214278/discussion-between-cyberdemon-and-alex).

Comment: I'm in the room. And I'm sorry - Bulk Insert is in Mule 4 only. So it is not flowVars but vars and way how attributes for Insert is different - you have to create parameters like {transactionDetailId:vars.transactionDetailId, product_code:payload.product_code}

Comment: Using the suggested solution, with ```vars``` if i log for example ```vars.transactionDetailId``` i get  three values. But if i use the ```vars``` inside may sql statement like this VALUES (#[vars.varTransactionDetailId],.......                               
Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.List, itemType=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, mimeType='*/*'}"

Comment: using the solution with parameters the error change in :                                     
                                                                                                                             
 ```Message               : "Cannot coerce Object ({transactionDetailId: ["CC12345", "DD12345", "SS12345"] as Array {encoding: "...) to Array

2| {
 |  ...
6| amount: vars.varAmount}```

Comment: In your example transactionDetailId is not array. If it is array then you need create big array of similar items to insert accounting to this transactionDetailId array or use forEach for the transactionDetailId and then Bulk Insert for each transactionDetailId element.

Comment: this is my params... ``` {
transactionDetailId: vars.varTransactionDetailId``` ,   than i try ```VALUES(:transactionDetailId,```  transactionId is not an array but an INT

Comment: You should pass array of items to Bulk Insert. Like [{transactionDetailId:"CC1234"},{transactionDetailId:"DD1234"}]. Then in the SQL parameters you use #[transactionDetailId:payload.transactionDetailId]. And then in SQL you use values(:transactionDetailId)

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/mule-4-database-connector-bulk-insert

Comment: it doesn't work...  i set a payload map, put my params inside the BULK INSERT and pass them inside my query values, but nothing.....   If i log ```payload.transactionDetailIdParam``` i get  ```.LoggerMessageProcessor: [[CC12345, DD12345, SS12345]] ```

Comment: Almost here. See you have array of arrays [[]]. You need one array [].

Comment: yes... but i dunno why!  so I have changed my approach. Im using a Batch Job. So the question is: inside my job step, i have to put a for each? or there's another way to accomplish  my mission?